# Is there a way to bypass Enterprise Enrollment Chrome OS DELL 3100

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

[Chrome OS BOOT UP SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dMoE.jpg)
When I POWERWASH my MANAGED Chromebook I can't bypass the **Wi-Fi** *setup* screen. Which **automatically enrolls** my Chromebook to my school but I don't want to **take apart** my chromebook without **damaging** the chromebook. **If I have to** do this then I will other wise I'm looking for another method. This is annoying and frustrating and I just wish IT Admins would let us wipe chromebooks without force-enroll. I have also heard that you could spam dev mode on chromebook but I don't want to risk it and it won't turn on dev mode anyways.

Comment: Only your school can de-provision and thus bypass enrolment.

Comment: If enrollment were easily bypassed there would be no point to it. Your school owns the device and has the right and the responsibility to manage them. You do not own this computer, and you do not have the right to do with it as you please. You are asking us to assist in theft, to put things bluntly, but accurately.